# VS2013 Update 3 incredibly slow - devenv.exe!!IsAssertEtwEnabled guilty thread

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

VS2013 Update 3 is incredibly slow and I'm tearing my hair out.

From Process Explorer, it looks like IsAssertEtwEnabled is having fun with my CPU and al;so there is a lot of file access going on.

What does IsAssertEtwEnabled do and what could cause this?

Oh, and in safe mode everything works fine. But I have disabled all the extensions I can without uninstalling and it's still dead slow.

Cheers,

James

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579499/visual-studio-2013-update-2-maxes-out-core (which fixed my problem)

Answer (score 1):

DevExpress Assembly Deployment Tool v1.1 with DevExpress 13.2.7

I have discovered why my Visual Studio Environment has been so slow (unusably slow – 10 minutes to do 5 second tasks – locked application for 10 minutes at a time).

Solution is to uninstall VS extension DevExpress Assembly Deployment Tool v1.1.
As detailed here:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q570295