# Poor VS Performance - High CPU on IsAssertEtwEnabled

Tags: performance, visual-studio, plugins, visual-studio-2013

I'm running Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and have been seeing high CPU usages and noticeable delay on simple UI menu navigation and basic text editing.

Using [ProcessExplorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) I took a screenshot which shows one thread is doing a lot of CPU in something called **IsAssertEtwEnabled**:

[image: Process Explorer Screenshot]

The screenshot was captured randomly scrolling up and down in the Extensions and Updates window.

> Any ideas how to speed up performance?

And yes I'm running several plugins, but I'd prefer to keep them, or at least find a way to isolate which one is causing this.

And I've reviewed a similar issue ([VS2013 Update 3 incredibly slow - devenv.exe!!IsAssertEtwEnabled guilty thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26220685/vs2013-update-3-incredibly-slow-devenv-exeisassertetwenabled-guilty-thread)), but I don't have anything from DevExpress installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 maxes out core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579499/visual-studio-2013-update-2-maxes-out-core)

Comment: Seeing this exact same issue on VS2015 Update3

Comment: Ya, I still get in VS2015.  Maybe 2017 will be better?  Think that version has plugin profiling to help find bad actors.  O, and I did hear a rumor at one point that this might be related to Code Lens

Comment: Funny, I observe this in VS 2017 on a VM, which runs on in a  host PC with 64 GB of memory, two SSDs (one dedicated to VM), and 10 cores (VM is allowed to run on 8 of them), and latest NVIDIA RTX 2060 GPU. Interestingly, CPU is not loaded at all, and there is plenty of free memory. However, VS is slow, and all system UI becomes slower and slower if I start more and more VS instances. And the same stack trace...

Comment: @sich more funny: sept. 2021 with VS2019 very same issue

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this is caused by browserLink going rogue (or it was for me anyway)

You can disable it next time the issue occurs:

[image]

For me when I disabled it I immediately got my CPU back. I personally was linking to chrome though I'm not sure it makes a difference.

I guess if you use it hopefully it will be fixed in a new version...

Comment: Thanks for posting; unfortunately I've already turned off Browser Link as I knew it causes high CPU.  Please leave this here though in case it helps anyone.  And any other ideas?

Comment: @PhilipPittle when I was looking around I saw similar complaints around dev-express and webessentials again depends if you have these but if you do it could be worth turning them off to see if it fixes the issue (unfortunately disabling an extension takes a restart of VS so its a bit harder to tell if it helps) Sounds like VS should probably do some work on rogue modules anyway

Answer (score 4):

Try to disable extensions one by one.

I fixed the issue by clearing ReSharper cache (VS 2015 CE).

ReSharper > Options > General > Clear Caches > Restart Visual Studio

@Sergii noticed that it's possible to delete the cache data directly in file system (`%localappdata%\JetBrains\Transient`).

Comment: This suggestion helped me to solve the issue of Visual Studio getting completely stuck on opening a solution. However, I had to clear ReSharper cache directly on disk, since in VS this can be done only after a solution has been opened.

Comment: Didn't tried to clear the cache, but disabling ReSharper definitely solved the issue!