# Visual Studio Hangs when switching from one page to another

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a winforms application that I'm using in Visual Studio 2015. When I switch from one form design page to another, VS hangs for 15-25 seconds each time.

I have no extensions installed except Git source control.
I have deleted the contents of the c:\users...\AppData\Microsoft\Visual Studio\14.0 folder.
I have reinstalled Visual Studio.
I have repaired Visual Studio (repeatedly.)
Starting in safe mode doesn't make any difference.
I have all Visual Studio updates installed.

The PC is a 2 month old beast (lots of RAM and CPU) with dual SSDs and Windows 10.

ProcExp says that IsAssertETWEnabled is the process that's using up the CPU during the hang.

Any advice/help is appreciated.

---UPDATE---
It ONLY does this when switching from one design view tab to another. No hang when in the code file or in the designer.vb file. Those move seamlessly.

Comment: Just a note that I have still not found a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the mention of "IsAssertETWEnabled"; have you checked this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29664712/1240570

The post is specific to VS 2013, but it looks similar to the problem in VS 2015.

For me the BrowserLink feature was causing more problems than it appeared to solve.. so I disabled it on my system.

Comment: It's a WinForms app, not a web app, so there is no BrowserLink setting option available.

Comment: I see; thought it could still be relevant but perhaps not.