# Visual Studio 2015 running as administrator uses a lot of CPU

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have a setup with Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 on a mac with VMWare Fusion 7.
Visual Studio 2015 is running fine, but when i want to debug i need to close VS2015 and run it as administrator.

This is working ok, but after a while it start to use a lot of CPU and the fans starts to go crazy, and the whole machine is getting slow. 
This only happens when running VS2015 as adminitrator.

Anyone know how to fix this or why this happens?

Comment: upvote https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2036016/after-close-process-is-still-running-with-hight-cpu-use

Answer (score 21):

Please check if you have Enable Browser Link set to on.

[image: http://shrani.si/f/0/Hg/HiyN7X6/error.jpg]

If so, turn it off :)

EDIT:
[Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 maxes out core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579499/visual-studio-2013-update-2-maxes-out-core)

Comment: Thank you! I unchecked this option and my Visual Studios went from a constant 15% cpu and growing memory usage to <2% and stable memory usage.

Comment: this saved my hair :')

Answer (score 15):

The Microsoft Source control provider for git was the culprit for me. Once i turned of off processor usage dropped from an average of 40-55 % to 0-5%

Comment: How did you turn it off?

Comment: Turn off here: Tools > Options > Source Control

Comment: it seems any source control does it. mine running Ankh SVN. looked in the resource monitor and can tell for sure its Ankh.. in other thread guy complained about TFS.. So it seems VS has a bug when it comes to integration with a source control

Comment: This was it - pegged at 100% CPU until I disabled "Git" under Tools > Options > Source Control - TY!  .. Terrible work MS

Answer (score 8):

If you're sure the root cause is not your application you can try to identify the problem using the *Windows Performance Toolkit (WPT)* which is part of the [Windows Assessment and Deployment Toolkit (ADK)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/dn913721.aspx) for Windows 10 (see the bottom of the page).

The *Windows Performance Analyzer* allows you to view a lot of metrics related to CPU captured in trace and identify the process, thread, module and even DCP/ISR function that might cause the high usage. This might give you an idea of where the problem lies, eg. by identifying the system module that gets called etc.

[image]

[image]

Microsoft provides a detailed CPU Analysis guide including some techniques on how to identify potential issues here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj679884.aspx

For a more specific answer you should try to run a trace and share the findings here.

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/07/20/performance-and-diagnostic-tools-in-visual-studio-2015.aspx

Start second instance of devenv -> Start perfomance analizer and attach it to your first devenv; 
so you will able analize report and check what eat CPU;

Answer (score 0):

This suspect the issue was caused by a bug in the IDE itself. After many months of experimenting with turning off things like Resharper or the Microsoft Git Provider along came the VS 2015 Update 2 and it appears to have resolved the issue!

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx