# Memory leak with Visual Studio running alongside web application

Tags: c#, jquery, visual-studio-2013, browser-link

I'm running a web application with models defined in C# and views being in HTML5, client-side business logic is JavaScript/jQuery. I've noticed something odd recently. Whenever both Visual Studio and my web application are running simultaneously, the browser memory usage starts to climb. It is worse in IE and Chrome, but likewise substantial in Firefox (all the latest versions of these browsers). Also, the memory usage of Visual Studio starts to climb. The CPU usage for the browser hovers in the teens, normally hovering around 0 otherwise.

Once I close down either the web application, or Visual Studio, the memory stops growing, and indeed, closing Visual Studio often allows the browser to run its garbage collection and clean up the mess. I suspect this has something to do with some sort of background debugging going on. I'm surprised that googling this hasn't turned up a similar issue for somebody somewhere in the world, and I suspect it's some kind of configuration setting in my IDE. Visual Studio 2013 Premium. I've reset my settings (Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings, with no effect. Building in Release mode likewise seems to have no effect. I'll keep hunting this one down, but has anyone here seen anything like this and resolved it?

**edit:** I have recently been debugging some dynamic code using the [debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) keyword. I've commented that out, and am still seeing the same results. But I wonder if there isn't some lingering effect from using this in the first place?

**edit:** Updating Resharper from 8.2 to 9.2 didn't help either.

**edit:** Apparently this issue [has been seen before and reported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24579499/visual-studio-2013-update-2-maxes-out-core/27521171#27521171), if you just know what to google for.

Comment: Visual Studio has a browser link feature that causes the web app to poll Visual Studio in case you have changed a file. Could it be that? (In my VS there is a small refresh icon in the debug menu with a drop down. In there you can disable this feature).

Comment: I'll take a look in a bit and let you know. Right now I've just updated my Resharper version on a suggestion from a colleague. Ah the fun of chasing down memory leaks....

Comment: @NigelEllis, Would you mind moving your comment to an answer? That solved it. This must have accidentally gotten enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio has a browser link feature that causes the web app to poll Visual Studio in case you have changed a file.

In VS there is a small refresh icon in the debug menu with a drop down. In there you can disable this feature.

Answer (score 1):

Did you trying running the application without debugging? (Ctrl+F5)

To enable VS debug the browser more info is needed specifically things like scripts and eval code are needed even after use. So, running the browser with debugging enabled will use more memory and cause memory to grow with time.